# setCC : Swift Mailer and Mandrill

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, mandrill

I am trying to send an email with a CC email address. Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't work.
To set the CC address, I use the function setCc() like this :

```
   $mailLogger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
            $this->mailer->registerPlugin(new 
    \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($mailLogger));

    /** @var \Swift_Message $message */
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($from_array)
        ->setTo(trim($to_email))
        ->setCc('test@test.com')
        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
```

I receive the email on the Cc address but it doesn't appear as 'Cc'. 
Also, in Mandrill dashboard, I can see that two different emails has been sent.

Is there a way to send mail with Cc with SwiftMailer and Mandrill ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead of:

```
->setCc('test@test.com')
```

use:

```
->addCc('test@test.com')
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#setting-cc-recipients), `setCc` is used to add several addresses simultaneously using an array. If you want to add 1 address, use `addCc`.